# Visual C++ 2010 error. The system cannot find the file specified when running LibICP

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, cmake

There is a [code](http://www.cvlibs.net/software/libicp/) for running **libIcp** for Andreas Geiger. I downloaded the code, and build the sln based on CMAKELISts.txt. Everything good so far.

According "readme.txt" I Opened the resulting Visual Studio solution with Visual Studio and Switched to 'Release' mode, build all and run the demo program. but 1st this window came up:

[image]

And Then I got this error:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not run the ALL_BUILD target it does not create an executable. It is there to force building the entire solution. Select an application target from the solution in Solution Explorer. Right click on that target and click set as start up project. This option should be around in the middle of the popup menu.